# Can't select bones in weight-paint mode

Tags: rigging, armature, weight-painting

I was able to weight paint fine the other day but my model did not behave or look right at all after porting to unreal.

So I deleted all the armature, I'm using the Game-Rig tools add-on, started over, parented the mesh to the armature with automatic weights, fixed errors with another add-on and things seemed good but the weights are all very low, light green, so the armature and mesh aren't synced 100%.

I go to weight paint and for some reason I cannot select any bones.

I can't even get the armature to stay in pose mode, once I shift click the mesh it takes the armature out of pose mode and I cant select bones.

I've gone through the preferences, I've deleted the keymap that could've been messing with things, I also made sure object lock mode was off.

I'm not sure what is happening and I just need to weight paint again.

[image]

Comment: Have you parented the mesh object to the armature with an Armature Deform option? Please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/